# ZIP Contents of inner directory without it's folder structure

Tags: linux, shell, unix, zip

Folder strucure

```
.
├── Folder A
└── Folder B
    └── Folder C
        └── Folder D
            ├── 1.txt
            ├── Folder X
            └── 2.html
```

I'm running script in Unix (from Folder `Root Folder` which contains `Folder A and B` with automation tools and want to zip the contents of `Folder D` only without persisting folder structure - but also want to zip `Folder X`

so unzipped structure will look like :

```
Environment.zip
├── 1.txt
├── Folder X
└── 2.html
```

Command I ran is : `ZIP -r -j Environment.zip ./Folder B/Folder C/Folder D/*`

but that didn't help and some how it created folder structure inside ZIP File.

**NOTE : I can't CD into Folder B-C-D so need to execute command from root folder**

Help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: cd "Folder B/Folder C/Folder D"; zip ...

Comment: Can't do CD into inner folders.

Comment: mkdir Folder-where-cd-is-allowed; ln -s Folder\ B/Folder\ C/Folder\ D/* Folder-where-cd-is-allowed; cd Folder-where-cd-is-allowed; zip ...; cd -;rm Folder-where-cd-is-allowed